# Why is the MAC address returned from nmap different from real MAC address on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, nmap

I am using nmap to discover devices on my network. I ran `nmap -sn 192.168.1.100/24` and it printed out multiple hosts, one of which is my iPhone. However, the MAC address returned from nmap is different from the one on my iPhone (from going to Settings -> About -> Wifi address).

Which one is the real one and how can I discover it?

Also I would like to compare the IP address. I was able to find the IP address for my iPhone using nmap but not able to find it anywhere in the settings next to Wifi address despite websites which shows them next to each other. Where can I find out my phones IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Actually your Iphone has hidden the real MAC address.

You should check Setting -> WiFi -> Info icon next to WiFi icon.

You will see the `Private address` is turning on.

`WiFi-Address` field is your result of nmap command.